# How to make File Reading Platform Independent in Java

Tags: java, maven, file-io, jar, file-handling

Hi I am using Maven for Selenium automation tests using Java. I am using Excel Sheet to read data for filling up a registration form. Now It is a normal Maven archetype.

```
src
--main
  --java
    --mypackage for coding goes here.
  --resources
    --data
      -- the excel sheet
--test
  -- some stuff here under java
```

currently if I want to read a file I am writing src/main/resources/data/theexcelsheet.xlsx
but when I share this jar, I think this will break and I don't want this to break if I package this jar.

How do I make it platform or format independent.

I am using APACHE POI Api if you are thinking how I am reading files.

Someone reading gave me idea that I might be able to use MANIFEST files to do this but I am not sure, can someone help?

Comment: You *think*. What have you tried? Any actual incidents?

Comment: I could not find any substantial information, also checked file class for this but did not get it how it will help me in my case. so I thought let me put it here and take help.

Comment: Will the files always be inside the jar? Then you should use 'Class#getResourceAsStream()'.

Comment: okay. I got it. Will try to do that. Thanks maba once again for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use getResource() to point to your file, the syntax of the path always uses `/` to separate the components, never `\` so you do not have to worry.

In general, outside of a jar, for example if you want to save application settings in a folder, you have to use a OS specific separator - you can obtain it this way:

`System.out.println("my" + File.separator + "dir");`

Returns `my\dir` on Win and `my/dir` on Linux

Of course, that's not enough as you cannot use hardcoded paths like the "c:" drive, but you can get the most common paths reading the System class properties, eg:

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.home"));
```

returns `C:\Users\piero` in Windows7 and `/home/piero` in Linux

Comment: Thank you very much. I think this could be helpful, http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html#How_do_I_add_resources_to_my_JAR