# How to read file at the same location of my jar, platform independent way?

Tags: java

I have a folder in it, there is a file named as `readme.txt`. My application will be run on the both Linux and DOS environment. Without writing full path like "c::\ ... \" or "~/Desktop ...", how can I read the file content with Java in Eclipse?

Directory structure

```
 project home path
    | ------ src // (folder)
    | ------ test // (folder)
    | ------ resource // (folder)
                | -------- datasetX // (folder)
                               | ------- readme.txt
```

I have done but not worked.

```
this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("readme.txt")
```

UPDATE 1: If possible,

I donot want readme.txt be in the Jar file at the end. Resource shuold be just optional folder, and it should not be distributed with Jar file.

*Just inform you to not do same mistake, this question is closed as dublicate with [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13316653/how-to-make-file-reading-platform-independent-in-java) without even comparing both. Even Answer in [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13316653/how-to-make-file-reading-platform-independent-in-java) not applicable to mine.*

Answer (score 1):

if your scope is just for IDE then eclipse sets current directory to the root of the project by default and you can navigate from there,

for example

```
File readMe = new File("./resource/datasetX/readme.txt");
```

if your app is going to be exported as JAR at some point then make sure you put `readme.txt` in classpath and read it as resource with proper path